# SignalR Help passing a List<string> to client

Tags: c#, json.net, signalr

Using SignalR and had no problems until now. This may be a simple question but I'm stumped.

I have a C# object below that I send to the client:

```
public class Message
{
    // Notifications
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int zoneCount { get; set; }

    public string CntrX { get; set; }
    public string CntrY { get; set; }

    // Polygon Overlays
    List<string>  pointList = new List<string>()
}
```

I'll add to pointList that's defined in the C# object;

```
    pointList.Add(soveVarX, soneVarY);
```

And in my client (javascript) the SignalR message is received like this:

```
 messenger.client.add = function (message){
 rmPoly = [{}];

    // And then to push...

       var sep = ',';
       var rmPoly = [];
            var len = messages.zoneCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var obj = {
                   x: gPoints [0],
                   y: gPoints [1],
               };
        rmPoly.push(obj); 
 };
```

I'm trying to push my pointList as an object to the object array called rmPoly in the client. So far I've tried this:

```
    var str1= message.pointList[0]; //<------How to get the List object?
    var  gPoints = str1.split(",");
```

And then to push...

```
        var rmPoly = [];
            var len = messages.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var obj = {
                   x: gPoints [0],
                   y: gPoints [1],
               };
        rmPoly.push(obj);
```

However message.pointList[0] has no value/undefined.

Any suggestions or more viable solutions?

Thanks vtotola for the answer!!... knew it was something easy I missed.
Also this may help someone in the future.

I was able to access the list in SignalR and push the object to array below:

```
 messenger.client.add = function (message) {
    var str1;
    var gPoints;
    var rmPoly = [];

    var len = message.PointList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            str1 = message.PointList[i];
            gPoints = str1.split(",");
            rmPoly.push({ x: gPoints[0], y: gPoints[1] });
    };
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code, pointList is a private field, and it wont be seriazized. Make it a public property.

```
public class Message
{
    // Notifications
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int zoneCount { get; set; }

    public string CntrX { get; set; }
    public string CntrY { get; set; }

    // Polygon Overlays
    public List<string>  PointList {get; set;}
}
```

Cheers.